# QT FontMetrics::BoundingRect wrong size

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I'm using Qt 5.2 and I'm currently trying to print a table from a `QTableView`, but I got this problem calculating the rows height by its content. What I got now is the cycle below, which loops through `QTableView` rows and gets height for each row using `boundingRect` function.

```
for(int r=0; r<rows; ++r) {
    //tempTable.resizeRowToContents(r);
    QString str = tempTable.model()->data(tempTable.model()->index(r,0)).toString();
    QFontMetrics fm(tempTable.font());
    QRect rect = fm.boundingRect(0,0,tempTable.columnWidth(0),0,(Qt::TextWordWrap),str);
    tempTable.setRowHeight(r,rect.size().height());
    totalHeight += tempTable.rowHeight(r);
}
```

Unfortunately, this function returns some weird result, making the big padding for strings:
[image]

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Doesn't `resizeRowToContents()` work? I see, you commented it out.

Comment: @vahancho Same result with `resizeRowToContents()`.

Comment: Is it possible, that your string has a lot of space characters in front? Did you try to trim them out?

Comment: @vahancho Yes, I did check for spaces and trimmed them all. No effect. I'm also certain that it got something with `QFontMetrics` and `Qt::TextWordWrap`. Looks like the function returns extra padding for every new line or a word. Maybe there is another way to get the wrapped string height?

Answer (score 1):

So, finally, I found the part of my code which was causing the trouble. This string,

```
tempTable.horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

which I put in order to stretch the columns to the page width, somehow affected the behavior of `boundingRect` in unexpected way. After I removed it and set each columns width using `setColumnWidth` function, everything looks good.